# easy double cumulative function

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $W$ be a r.a. with cumulative function:

$F_W(x) =$ 
\begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } w<0 \\ w/4, & \mbox{if 0 $\leq$$ w<1$} \\1, & \mbox{if } w\geq1 \\ \end{cases}

What does it to mean to find $prob(W\leq\ z, W<1)$?

Can I say $prob(W\leq\ z, W<1) = F_W(z)F_W(1^-)$?

Thanks for your help.

KB

Comment: By the comma between $W \le z$ and $W<1$ do you mean a logical "and"? Or is it two separate questions? [notation seems unclear] Anyway one would not *multiply* two values of a cumulative to find any probability, usually they are subtracted. So if you clear up what the comma means someone could maybe help.

Comment: Yes I mean that the two conditions must be together true. Could it be $\\F_W(x)$ if $w < 1$ and $0$, $else$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want both $W < z$ and $W<1$ to hold at once, it depends on where $z$ is. In case $z<1$ the two conditions intersect to just $W < z$ and the probability of that is $F_W(z-)=z/4.$ On the other hand if $z \ge 1$ then the two conditions intersect to $W < 1$ and the probability is $F_W(1-)=1/4.$

Note that since there is a jump of size $3/4$ as $w$ goes from just before $1$ to $1$ there is a probability of $3/4$ that $W$ is *exactly* equal to $1$. So this cumulative is that of a random variable of "mixed" type, neither classification of continuous or discrete applies.

Edit: Forgot the case where $z<0$ in which case the probability is $0$ because of definition of $F_W.$